# Executing cmd commands in texstudio

Tags: cmd, tex

I'm trying to execute some cmd command in textstudio. In particular i would like to create a new folder where i will put some files after compiling finishes. In "option -> build -> precompile" I add the following:

[image]

But after a while a receive the rerror Error: Command crashed: "C:/Windows/System32/cmd.exe" "mkdir out"

I have solved with: cmd.exe /C mkdir out > nul 2> nul 
But the command output continues to be shown.

Comment: I have changed the command with cmd.exe /C mkdir out > nul 2> nul and now works. My problem now is that the command shows the output even if redirection is used.

Comment: What would be the equivalent in Linux? I want to run `export LC_ALL="en_US"` as a user command.